# In an Xcode4 plugin, how does one add a pane to Xcode's preferences?

Tags: xcode, plugins, xcode4, nspreferencepane

The [Code Pilot Xcode plugin](http://codepilot.cc/) adds its own preference pane to Xcode's preferences, but none of the open-source Xcode plugins I've looked at have preference panes.  How do I go about adding a preference pane to Xcode's preferences from an Xcode plugin (specifically under Xcode 4)?